# Returning value of the Type passed in the function

Tags: c#, types, random

I am writing a random-value generator in C#, this generic function should return value of `Type` `Bool`, `Int64`, `Int32`, `Double` depending on the Type passed. So, I can pass the `System.Type` as a method parameter, but how should I define the return type?

For example

`GetRandomValueByType(TypeCode.Boolean)`  <--- Returns Boolean
`GetRandomValueByType(TypeCode.Double)`   <--- Returns Double
`GetRandomValueByType(TypeCode.Int32)`  <--- Returns Int32

And so on and so forth.

Thank you!

---------------------------EDIT--------------------------------

This is the code I used:

```
if (ta.IsPrimitive || Type.GetTypeCode(ta) == TypeCode.String)
{
    Random rnd = new Random();
    var buffer = new byte[sizeof(Int64)];
    rnd.NextBytes(buffer);
    switch (Type.GetTypeCode(ta))
    {
        case TypeCode.Boolean:
            oArr[ctr] = (rnd.Next(100) % 2 == 0);
            break;
        case TypeCode.Byte:
            oArr[ctr] = buffer[0];
            break;
        case TypeCode.SByte:
            oArr[ctr] = (sbyte)buffer[0];
            break;
        case TypeCode.Char:
            oArr[ctr] = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor(26 * rnd.NextDouble() + 65));
            break;
        case TypeCode.Decimal:
            oArr[ctr] = NextDecimal(rnd);
            break;
        case TypeCode.Double:
            oArr[ctr] = rnd.NextDouble() * rnd.Next(Int32.MaxValue);
            break;
        case TypeCode.Single:
            var buf = new byte[sizeof(Single)];
            rnd.NextBytes(buf);
            oArr[ctr] = BitConverter.ToSingle(buffer, 0);
            break;
        case TypeCode.Int32:
            oArr[ctr] = rnd.Next(Int32.MinValue, Int32.MaxValue);
            break;
        case TypeCode.UInt32:
            oArr[ctr] = rnd.Next(Int32.MaxValue) + (rnd.Next(100) % 2) * rnd.Next(Int32.MaxValue);
            break;
        case TypeCode.Int64:
            oArr[ctr] = BitConverter.ToInt64(buffer, 0);
            break;
        case TypeCode.UInt64:
            oArr[ctr] = BitConverter.ToUInt64(buffer, 0);
            break;
        case TypeCode.Int16:
            oArr[ctr] = rnd.Next(Int16.MaxValue);
            break;
        case TypeCode.UInt16:
            oArr[ctr] = rnd.Next(Int16.MaxValue) + (rnd.Next(100) % 2) * rnd.Next(Int16.MaxValue);
            break;
        case TypeCode.String:
            oArr[ctr] = RandomString(rnd.Next(100));
            break;
        default:
            oArr[ctr] = 0;
            break;
    }
}
else
{
    oArr[ctr] = getInstance(dllFile, ta.Name);
}
```

Comment: As the others below said, generics. However, to limit it to specific Types, since these are likely being split within your method anyway, why not just overload the method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generics may be handy here - you could do something like:

```
T GetRandomValueByType<T>() where T : IConvertible
{
   // Compute random...
   return Convert.ChangeType(randomValue, typeof(T));
}
```

This would then be called via:

```
double value = GetRandomValueByType<double>();
```

However, this isn't entirely safe (not that using `System.Type` is either), as you could still pass a type which implemented `IConvertible` but was inappropriate.

---

Given your comment, I would recommend just making separate methods:

```
bool GetRandomBoolean() { // ...
double GetRandomDouble() { // ...
int GetRandomInt() { // ...
```

If you're already going to switch on the type, and make specific implementations, this provides a cleaner, safer way to handle it.  By having separate methods, you eliminate the possibility of passing an incorrect type, and simplify the API.

Comment: What is the way to determine type of `T`? I was thinking of using switch-case but it doesn't recognise `T` as a variable.

Comment: @babbupandey You can use `typeof(T)` to get a `System.Type`, and check against it.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to make these methods generic:

```
T GetRandomValueByType<T>()
{
    ...
}

GetRandomValueByType<Boolean>();
GetRandomValueByType<Double>();
GetRandomValueByType<Int32>();
```

Answer (score 0):

You an generic implementation:

```
    public class Generic
    {
      public static T GetRandomValueByType<T>(T parameter)
      {
        switch(typeof(T))
        {
            case System.Int32:
                Random r = new Random();
                return (T)r.Next();
            case System.Guid:
                return (T)Guid.NewGuid();
            // other cases here...
}
      }
    }
```

and use something like this:

```
var value = Generic.GetRandomValueByType<bool>();
```

You also can use `Random` class to provide some random value, as the sample.